# Angularjs $http call gives "no access-control-allow-origin header" error

Tags: angularjs

I am calling one java by using $http in angularjs but I am getting this  error in Chrome:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.168.1.104:8080/etts/Abilityscore?userid=1. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

My code is:

```
var countryApp = angular.module('countryApp', []);
         countryApp.controller('CountryCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
             alert("eee")
           $http.get('http://192.168.1.104:8080/etts/Abilityscore?userid=1
   ').success(function(data) {
             $scope.countries = data;
               var sum = 0; 
               var tval = 0;
               for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
                 sum += parseInt(data[i]['getval'], 10);
                 tval += parseInt(data[i]['totalval'], 10); 


               }
```

Comment: You are sending request to different domain/port which is not allowed by CORS policy.

Comment: As said above - it is not allowed to make cross domain requests unless the requested service allows it. I suggest you read about CORS, saves a lot of hassle in the future - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS